# how to make pytest fail on shellcommand invocation failure

Tags: python, pytest, exit-code

For a python pytest file with contents of:

```
import os
def test_that():
    print("step 1: should work")
    os.system("echo hello")
    
    print("step 2: should fail")
    os.system("asdf_failing_non_existing_command")
```

and an invocation of pytest like:

```
 pytest -s testing.py
```

The output is:

```
1 passed
```

I would expect the test to fail. How can I get the exit code from os system call to influence the test failure and actually fail the test?

Comment: can you try with `subprocess` https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get the exit code from os system call to influence the test failure and actually fail the test?

Don't use `os.system`.  (You almost never need it, and the docs are [pretty strong](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) on using `subprocess` instead).

With subprocess:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["echo", "hi"], check=True)
subprocess.run(["asdfasdfasdfdas"], check=True)
```

Or you can use os.system and check yourself, but why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

You can assert that the result of `os.system()` is equal to 0:

```py
import os
def test_that():
    print("step 1: should work")
    assert os.system("echo hello") == 0
    
    print("step 2: should fail")
    assert os.system("asdf_failing_non_existing_command") == 0
```

The output is:

```bash
    def test_that():
        print("step 1: should work")
        assert os.system("echo hello") == 0

        print("step 2: should fail")
>       assert os.system("asdf_failing_non_existing_command") == 0
E       AssertionError: assert 1 == 0
E        +  where 1 = <built-in function system>('asdf_failing_non_existing_command')
E        +    where <built-in function system> = os.system

test.py:7: AssertionError
============================================================================== short test summary info =============================================================================== 
FAILED test.py::test_that - AssertionError: assert 1 == 0
================================================================================= 1 failed in 0.16s ==================================================================================
```

Comment: great answer - I will accept the one above as it is cleaner

Comment: Thanks, the answer above is cleaner, you're right

Answer (score -1):

Use subprocess.getstatusoutput, just raise an Exception if the first item it returns (the return code) isn't 0.